# How can I delete the options from DB when the plugin is deleted?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, mysql

I am saving my plugin's data under the wp_options tables. How can I delete my plugin's data and saved options from there when the user deletes my plugin?
I know I can delete tables while plugin deletion, but how can I delete the data that are under the wp_options tables?
Thanks, and sorry if I sound nerdy :)

Comment: If you know how to delete tables on plugin delete, then deleting rows would be the same, you just need the proper SQL query to target the data your plugin created

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete options with register\_uninstall\_hook?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24600/how-can-i-delete-options-with-register-uninstall-hook)